# Error message showing DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Tags: server, dns

I site I own has the following error message on all browsers DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN. I have flushed the cache and updated the DNS with Googles public but neither have worked and not sure what the problem could be. Can anyone help?

Comment: It means the domain name was not found, probably the DNS configuration for your domain is faulty/missing, impossible to tell without knowing the actual domain name.

Answer (score 0):

If your DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN issue in a windows computer, You can solve this issue using **DNS Client Service restarting**.

1. Open Command Prompt (Windows key + R key), type `services.msc` -->
   Enter.
2. Now open services window, Find "DNS Client" service.
3. Right click, select Restart.

Otherwise if you not try Release and Renew IP Address, It should be worked. So, Follow 8 options to how to fix [DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN](https://dnsprobefix.com)

Comment: I followed these steps but the all the tasks (Start, Stop, Pause, Resume, Restart) are grayed out. I also tried again running it as an administrator but I get the same result